# How to create a daemon container with interface terminal using docker-py?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm using docker python SDK `docker-py`, which is quite convenient. I look through the document, I still can't figure out how to create a daemon container with interface terminal,that is to say, if in the shell, this equals to the command `docker run -dit image`.

I know docker-py right now offers the `client.containers.run` to run a contaniner, and with `deatch` argument I can run it as a daemon. However, I want start it with a interface terminal.

'Cause my further code would access to the container from the remote server. Is there any way to create it directly with docker-py instead of using `os.system(docker run -dit image)`?

Comment: Like `docker run`, [`client.containers.run` has many options](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html).  Those should correspond to all of the `docker run` command-line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After swimming in the doc for a while, I figure it out.
The command `docker run -dit image` in docker-py is `client.containers.run(image,tty=True,stdin_open=True, detach=True)` This would work. Thank u David.